# PANDAS: Splitting the list with arrays into list of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

When I print out my list it prints as

```
[array([7], dtype=int64), 
 array([11], dtype=int64), 
 array([15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35, 39, 43, 47, 51, 55, 59, 63, 67], dtype=int64)]
```

But I want it like `[7,11,15,19,23, ...]`

I am using pandas to get the index value of columns which matches certain conditions, in 1st 2 conditions the values were unique hence it gives output array `array([7], dtype=int64), array([11], dtype=int64)`, but then one of the condition is matched by multiple index value of columns hence it produces  `array([15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35, 39, 43, 47, 51, 55, 59, 63, 67])`

But I want it as a list of numbers as `[7,11,15,19,23, ...]`

So what can I do?

Here is my code

```
dy= df.xs(0)
for id in dy:
    if 'ID' in str(id):
        #ID list Index Values
        zr= dy[dy==id].index.value 
        zr_list = zr_list.append(zr)
        print(zr_list)
```

Output

```
     [array([7], dtype=int64), 
     array([11], dtype=int64), 
     array([15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35, 39, 43, 47, 51, 55, 59, 63, 67], 
     dtype=int64)]
```

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

Comment: Please share the code you use to create the list.

Comment: Have added the code for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `extend()` instead of `append()`, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252711/3018835) makes abundantly clear. Change your line that uses `append` to:

```
zr_list = zr_list.extend(zr)
```

In short:

- `append`: appends the list as a single element to the original list
- `extend`: appends the list element by element to the original list

Comment: Thanks a lot also for the explanation! It worked well